# Проблемы с использованием diff

Tags: linux, diff

У меня есть два файла с контрольными суммами:

```
$ cat 1.txt
5e5d530860a9115 /etc/skel/.bash_logout
85306d27c70adb1 /etc/bash.bashrc
0831f7d5047cf0d /var/lib/alsa/asound.state
a02ab6bd8aca933 /usr/share/doc/baytrail-addons/changelog.gz
343648d67053e34 /etc/X11/xorg.conf
826360e87067664 /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43241b4-sdio.bin
37b0663acd47882 /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43241b4-sdio.txt
64394884768e6e6 /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.2.3.d.bseq
e6b515e47c663af /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.1.2d.d.bseq
eae7cf4947cf4a8 /lib/firmware/intel/fw_sst_0f28.bin-i2s_master
aabbb0c2adba80f /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.bseq
a85a699937df5ca /lib/firmware/intel/fw_sst_0f28.bin-tdm_slave
7f442ed66dc400c /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.8.bseq
84d2a4196ab5f6e /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.2.27.d.bseq
858015692380ace /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.0.2.3.d.bseq
909e2cf95e1cf45 /lib/firmware/intel/fw_sst_0f28.bin-i2s_slave
5b1d33f31f32ca3 /lib/firmware/intel/fw_sst_0f28.bin-tdm_master

$ cat 2.txt
5e5d530860a9115  /etc/skel/.bash_logout
85306d27c70adb1  /etc/bash.bashrc
cd72bd3f4f04572  /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43241b4-sdio.bin
6d05c9cd2905486  /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.2.3.d.bseq
d86ff7ab47998c3  /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.1.2d.d.bseq
aabbb0c2adba80f  /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.bseq
7f442ed66dc400c  /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.8.bseq
d9accecfa96f39e  /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.2.27.d.bseq
95af48721ab5ed7  /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.0.2.3.d.bseq
```

Я хочу сравнить их и использую для этого diff. Проблема в том, что начиная с 3 строки сравнение идет криво. Т.е. 3 строка должна быть помечена как отсутствующая во 2 файле, т.к. там нет такого пути, но вместо этого обозначена как измененная:

```
$ diff -w -y -W 160 1.txt 2.txt
5e5d530860a9115 /etc/skel/.bash_logout                      5e5d530860a9115  /etc/skel/.bash_logout
85306d27c70adb1 /etc/bash.bashrc                        85306d27c70adb1  /etc/bash.bashrc
0831f7d5047cf0d /var/lib/alsa/asound.state                    | cd72bd3f4f04572  /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43241b4-sdio.bin
a02ab6bd8aca933 /usr/share/doc/baytrail-addons/changelog.gz           | 6d05c9cd2905486  /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.2.3.d.bseq
343648d67053e34 /etc/X11/xorg.conf                        | d86ff7ab47998c3  /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.1.2d.d.bseq
826360e87067664 /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43241b4-sdio.bin           <
37b0663acd47882 /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43241b4-sdio.txt           <
64394884768e6e6 /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.2.3.d.bseq         <
e6b515e47c663af /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.1.2d.d.bseq        <
eae7cf4947cf4a8 /lib/firmware/intel/fw_sst_0f28.bin-i2s_master            <
aabbb0c2adba80f /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.bseq                aabbb0c2adba80f  /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.bseq
a85a699937df5ca /lib/firmware/intel/fw_sst_0f28.bin-tdm_slave             <
7f442ed66dc400c /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.8.bseq                7f442ed66dc400c  /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.8.bseq
84d2a4196ab5f6e /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.2.27.d.bseq        | d9accecfa96f39e  /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.2.27.d.bseq
858015692380ace /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.0.2.3.d.bseq          | 95af48721ab5ed7  /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.0.2.3.d.bseq
909e2cf95e1cf45 /lib/firmware/intel/fw_sst_0f28.bin-i2s_slave             <
5b1d33f31f32ca3 /lib/firmware/intel/fw_sst_0f28.bin-tdm_master            <
```

В чем может быть дело? Почему только часть файла сравнивается верно?

Comment: diff не настолько умный что бы игнорировать разницу в начале строки.

Comment: @AlexeyTen в строках 14-15 вывода diff разница только в контрольных суммах, строки отмечены |. Я не понимаю, почему 3 строка помечена как |, хотя должна быть <

Comment: А `mcdiff` из пакета `mc` тоже плохо показывает?